# Estimating Propensity Score via Regression Trees (in R Using rpart)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to estimate propensity scores in R. By this I mean that I am trying to estimate probability that an individual selects into treatment, where the selection into treatment is a binary variable. Typically people use logit or probit to estimate these. I was thinking of using regression trees.

Is it okay to use rpart "anova" method to estimate propensities? I think I cannot use classification tree because that gives a binary outcome whereas I want the continuous propensity score function i.e. how does probability of treatment changes as the continuous explanatory variables changes.

I am using the following command where x and z are continuous explanatory variables and d is a binary treatment variable and all 3 are observed for each individual and I want to estimate P(D=1|X,Z).

```
  cart = rpart(d~x+z, data=data, method="anova")

  data[,pz_c:=predict(cart, type = "vector")]
```

where the first command estimates the propensity and the second adds the predicted propensities to the data set for each individual.

I originally posted this on stackoverflow and was told to post thee question here instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logistic regression itself, since your target variable is binary.

While predicting, use `type = "prob"` 
This will provide the propensities which is basically just the probability of being a 1 or 0.

Comment: So is using cart "anova" correct? Should I instead use "class" method and predict propensities using type="prob"?

Comment: Use method = 'class' with type = 'prob'. As per your question, target variable is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this article. Helmreich, James & Pruzek, Robert. (2008). PSAgraphics: An R Package to Support Propensity Score Analysis. Journal of Statistical Software. 29. 10.18637/jss.v029.i06.

In section three, they show an example of how you can estimate propensity scores and stratify the data based on them.

There is also a good example in Valliant, Dever and Kreuter's book (2013) titled Practical Tools for Designing and Weighting Survey Samples in section "Adjustment for nonresponse". An important piece of advice they give is to set minbucket to 50 to assure that each class is not too small if you are going to use the propensity scores in weighting. This is done using the control option e.g., control=rpart.control(minbucket=50, cp=0).